# biztalk xslt - mapping

Tags: mapping, biztalk

I 'm a newbie on bts - just started yesterday, having a "tutor" giving me a a few concepts - after the first mapping  using bts tools (shipped on visual studio).
now the guy who is tutoring ask me to do that manually... i write my own xslt file.

since i never work with xslt befor i'm a little bit lost.
i had an "incomming" xml with a namespace wich i want to modify to an output xml, with a diferent namespace.
after that i had to pass directly values from one xml xml to another and to other values i had to sum or multiply .

incoming xml namespace = http://NWMessaging.CustomerOrder
outcoming xml namespace = http://FKMessaging.SupplierPO/

i have no ideia out to get values from 1st xml to 2nd one.

any tips to start?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you create a map in Visual Studio's BizTalk Mapper, it can generate the XSLT for you, which is perhaps the best way to begin to understand how XSLT works. This allows you to see what the namespaces will be set to, what linking nodes from your input to your output schema look like, etc.

In Visual Studio:

- go to the *Solution Explorer*
- right-click on your map file ([something].btm)
- select *Validate Map*
- after VS compiles and runs the validation, the *Output* pane will show you the location of the "output XSLT" file

Unless you are going to do really complex mappings, you likely won't need to know XSLT all that well. If you do need to do that, then you can always [pick up a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822075/best-book-to-learn-xslt).